# Designing classes for a scenario

Tags: design-patterns

This is a design question.
A program runs the back end of a website like Piazza. 
Some of the messages are posted by regular users (students), displaying the name of the author 
and time that is was posted. Other messages are posted by admin users (instructors and TAs) and 
contain the same information as well as the number of
times the message has been edited by the original author. 
When a message is posted, it appears with tags afterwards. Tags are strings that 
start with an @ sign. They are chosen by author of the message.
The system that keeps track of each message, its tags, who posted it, and links together
messages that are part of the same conversation is called the Message Board.
A user can request to only see posts with a particular tag. For example, a user can search
all messages that discuss design patterns by searching for@designPatterns.

1. Should classes UserMessage and AdminMessage implement the same interface?
2. Should classes UserMessage and AdminMessage extend a class other than object ?

Here is what I could think of -
class UserMessage extends Message
class AdminMessage extends Message

Now the AdminMessage contains extra information like storing the # of edits to
 the message. And since our MessageBoard provides the functionality to 
go over all the messages which contain a particular tag. So we will loop 
over a List and check if that message contains that particular 
tag

```
class Message {
private List<Tags> tags;
private string poster;
private string message;

public boolean hasTag(string tagName)
{
     // check if tagName is there in the list
}


}
```

Comment: By the above logic and thinking process Both should extend the class Message.

Comment: *Should classes UserMessage and AdminMessage implement the same interface?*  That depends.  You mentioned that administrators can edit their messages.  Can regular users edit their messages? If not, then their interface would necessarily be different.  *Should classes UserMessage and AdminMessage extend a class other than Object?* That depends on the answer to my question.  You can create an abstract Message class that UserMessage and AdminMessage extend.

Comment: The admin users can edit but normal users cannot. <br> Also what do you think about my reasoning above. The class Message that I have designed to be extended. Probably you are suggesting I should make this Message abstract and put abstract methods there for completeness

Comment: The Message class doesn't have to be abstract.  If there are methods that would have the same name and input parameters in UserMessage and AdminMessage, but have different implementations, then an abstract Message class makes sense.